# @Cacheable() not returning proper cache

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I am well aware that there are multiple questions on this topic, but I just can't get the sense of it. The problem seems to be that `@CachePut` does not add the new value to the @Cacheable list.

After debugging the problem I found out that the problem **seems** to be in the key.

Here is the code snippet

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "documents")
interface DocumentRepository {

@CachePut(key = "#a0.id")
Document save(Document document);

@Cacheable()
List<Document> findAll();
}
```

So when I invoke the save method, the key being used for caching is incrementing integer, or 1,2,3...
But when I try to get all documents, the cache uses SimpleKey[] as key. If I try to use the same key for @Cacheable, I get SpelEvaluationException, property 'id' cannot be found on null.

So what I am left with at the end is functional cache (the data is saved in the cache), but somehow I am not able to retrieve it.
The underlying cache implementation is EhCache.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you are expecting here.

It looks like you expect your `findAll` method to return the full content of the cache named `documents`. I don't think there is anything in the documentation that can let you conclude that this feature exists (it does not). It is also very fragile. If we were implementing that, `findAll` would return different results based on the state  of the cache. If someone would configure this cache to have a max size of 100 for instance. Or If the cache isn't warm-up on startup.

You can't expect a cache abstraction (or even a cache library) to maintain a synchronized view of "a list of objects". What `findAll` does is returning the entry that corresponds to a key with no argument (`new SimpleKey` by default).